# Plotly express shows Invalid property for latitude for choropleth map plot for python

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, geospatial, plotly-express

I am using these dataset " dataset tempat perlancongan Malaysia.csv" . In that I'm Passing the latitude and longitude for plotting the plot plot for spatial coordinate vs numerical feature .

error I got =

Value Error: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Choropleth: 'lat'

Comment: what's the code? that gave you the error?

Comment: If you provide the dataset and how you are passing the latitude and longitude it would be easier to guess what went wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- I don't speak Malay so can't fully find data set you partially reference.  Have used this one [pelancongan data](https://www.data.gov.my/data/en_US/dataset/lokasi-tempat-pelancongan-mengikut-daerah-di-negeri-selangor/resource/18b5c1e0-e362-41a2-935c-c35795df9d17)
- it's appears you have not understood what a **choropleth** is.  A **choropleth** uses polygons as the geometry, not points.  From fact you are trying to pass `lat` and the data I have found provided latitude and longitude your data supports a **scatter** not a **choropleth**

```
import requests, io
import plotly.express as px

# https://www.data.gov.my/data/en_US/dataset/lokasi-tempat-pelancongan-mengikut-daerah-di-negeri-selangor/resource/18b5c1e0-e362-41a2-935c-c35795df9d17
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get(
            "https://www.data.gov.my/data/en_US/datastore/dump/18b5c1e0-e362-41a2-935c-c35795df9d17"
        ).text
    )
)

px.scatter_geo(df, lat="LATITUDE", lon="LONGITUDE", hover_data=["NAMA"]).update_layout(
    geo_scope="asia", geo_fitbounds="locations"
)
```

[image]

#### mapbox ***

```
px.scatter_mapbox(
    df,
    lat="LATITUDE",
    lon="LONGITUDE",
    hover_data=["NAMA"],
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
)
```

[image]